# Woocommerce category display: Show subcategories & products excluding subcategory products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help on category display option for Woocommerce. 
In the Wordpress dashboard, I followed the below links to set up the category display option globally.
Appearance -> Customize -> Woocommerce -> Product Catalog -> Category display

There are three display options available.

1. Show products
2. Show subcategories
3. Show subcategories & products

Currently, the third option is selected and it shows subcategories and all the products under parent categories and subcategories.
However, I want to exclude all the products under subcategories.
In other words, I want to show subcategories and products under parent categories only.

I found the following snippet at several tutorial sites. The code works exactly the way I want but it also disables the admin products search and filter function (it returns no results regardless). 
Any idea why it happens?

```
function exclude_product_cat_children($wp_query) {
if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
$wp_query->set('tax_query', array(
                                 array (
                                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
                                    'include_children' => false
                                )
                              )
        );
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');
```

WP: v4.9.5 / Woocommerce: v3.3.4 / Theme: Storefront v2.2.8

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this issue insert the script between the:  if ( ! is_admin() ) { }

Full code:

```
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
function exclude_product_cat_children($wp_query) {
if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
    $wp_query->set('tax_query', array( 
                                    array (
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
                                        'include_children' => false
                                    ) 
                                 )
    );
  }
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me

```
function exclude_product_cat_children($wp_query) { 
if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
$wp_query->set('tax_query', array(
                                array (
                                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
                                    'include_children' => false
                                )
                             )
);
}
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');
```

Comment: How is this different to the one in the question?